# Change rounded Border Background of a button when it is pressed

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, properties, background

I created  a border outside the button control then my button has rounded corners :

```
<Border  Margin="0,-15,5,0" Height="50" CornerRadius="20"  BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#2b4e9f" >
                    <Border.Background>
                       White
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Button  Content="{Binding Path=StringFile.Match_Lens, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}"   Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="156" Click="button1_Click"   Foreground="#2b4e9f" >

 </Button>
</Border>
```

So my button is contained in a border which has a white background.
I would like to change the color of the border's background when my button is pressed.

This works with the button's background...I can't figure out how to do the same with the border control ...

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border"  
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"

                                >
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                       Green

                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>

                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't change background of the outer `Border` but one inside your `ControlTemplate` and you can do the same with `BorderBrush` so there's no need to wrap it with outer `Border`. Just bring everything into your `Style` and `Template`

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
   <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2b4e9f"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="border" CornerRadius="20" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Green"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="GreenYellow"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then just apply `Style` to your `Button`, as you do but without outer `Border`

```
<Button 
    Content="{Binding Path=StringFile.Match_Lens, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" 
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, you can leverage DataTriggers in this case

```
<Border  Margin="0,-15,5,0"
         Height="50"
         CornerRadius="20"
         BorderThickness="2"
         BorderBrush="#2b4e9f">
    <Button  Content="{Binding Path=StringFile.Match_Lens, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}"
             Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             FontSize="24"
             x:Name="button1"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Width="156"
             Click="button1_Click"
             Foreground="#2b4e9f">
    </Button>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed,ElementName=button1}"
                             Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

one point to note is that when you set some property via style triggers you can not set the same property inline, so I've move the Background property to setter. perhaps you may also want to know about [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <Border x:Name="border1"
            Margin="0,-15,5,0"
            Height="50"
            CornerRadius="20"
            BorderThickness="2"
            BorderBrush="#2b4e9f"
            Background="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsPressed, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ColorConverter}}">
        <Button x:Name="Button1"
                Content="foo"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                FontSize="24"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="156" />
    </Border>
```

And here is the converter,

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool flag = (bool)value;
        if (flag)
        {
            return Brushes.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```